# Difference between Deterministic Volatility Function approach and Ad Hoc Black Scholes?

Tags: volatility, black-scholes, implied-volatility

I am thoroughly confused after reading Dumas, Fleming & Whaley (1998) "Implied Volatility Functions: Empirical Tests".  Both the Ad Hoc BS Model and the Deterministic Volatility Function approaches in the paper seem to posit a structure for a function determining volatility and then run a regression to determine the coefficients. What is the difference between the two approaches? What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

At $t=0$, you have a vol surface $(T,K)\to\sigma(t=0,S_t=S_0,T,K)$

the hard question is which dynamics i.e $\sigma$ seen as $\sigma: (t,S_t)\to ((T,K)\to \sigma(t,S_t,T,K))$

and even, if you imagine that behind this, there is a deterministic function, you still have to suppose a dependence with respect to $S_t$

Here are two examples

1) $\sigma(t=0,S_t=S_0,T,K)=f(T-t,\ln(K/S_t))$ where $f$ is a deterministic function fitting your data at $t=0$ (kind of sticky moneyness)

2) $\sigma(t=0,S_t=S_0,T,K)=g(T-t,K)$ where $g$ is a deterministic function fitting your data at $t=0$ (kind of sticky strike)